# How do you isolate a single project in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

Whenever I Ctrl+Shift+W (close all tabs) in Eclipse and start or open a fresh project, the warnings and errors in the *Problems* view persist (from the previous projects in my workspace that were open in the past). How can I let Eclipse know that I want to focus on the current project only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This varies by release, but there is a filters dialog (Try using the down arrow in the Problems toolbar and choose "Filter Content").  You can set the scope to be "On any element in the same project".  The scope is determined using the current selection in one of the navigator views (Packager Explorer, Navigator, etc)